Create Vector from One-to-Many Dataframe in R
I have a dataframe with a one-to-many relationship where the one in the relationship are the column names and the many in the relationship are entries in the first column. I would like to create a vector or dataframe where the elements are selected from columns whose names match the entry in the first column. What follows is an example:
df <- data.frame(
  id = c('A','A','A','B','B','C'),
  A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  B = c(7,8,9,10,11,12),
  C = c(13,14,15,16,17,18),
  D = c(19,20,21,22,23,24)
)

The resulting vector or data frame should have the following elements:
1
2
3
10
11
18

I would like a second vector or dataframe (ideally the first and second are joined) which are the neighboring values to the right. The final results should therefore be
1  7
2  8
3  9
10 16
11 17
18 24

I am hoping for a solution which doesn't involve looping. Thank you for your help.

Thank you for these clever solutions. Some readers may be curious about my specific application. The rows are futures trading days and the columns are the assortment of futures contracts which actively trade. The table entries are the futures prices. The solution vector is the leading futures contract which is periodically rolled forward through time.

You can try
sapply(0:1, \(n, x=df[-1]) x[col(x) == match(df$id, names(x))+n])

or
t(mapply(\(i, j) t(df[i, j+0:1]), 1:nrow(df), match(df$id, names(df))))

Both gives
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    7
[2,]    2    8
[3,]    3    9
[4,]   10   16
[5,]   11   17
[6,]   18   24


here is another base R method. Should be efficient:
row_num <- seq_len(nrow(df))
col_num <- match(df$id, names(df)[-1])
matrix(df[-1][cbind(row_num, c(col_num, col_num + 1))], ncol = n)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    7
[2,]    2    8
[3,]    3    9
[4,]   10   16
[5,]   11   17
[6,]   18   24


With base R, we can make use of indexing [].
unname(t(sapply(1:nrow(df), \(x) {
  ind <- which(df[x, 1] == colnames(df))
  unlist(df[x, ind:(ind+1)])
})))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1    7   
[2,] 2    8   
[3,] 3    9   
[4,] 10   16  
[5,] 11   17  
[6,] 18   24  


Good idea! You can use str() to check your output. It's actually a matrix-like list, not a normal matrix. You may need unlist() out of df[x, ind:(ind+1)]

@DarrenTsai Thank you very much for your comment! You have again teach me something!

This is not an elegant dplyr solution, but might be a fun one if you are interested
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    pivot_longer(-id) %>%
    filter((as.integer(factor(name)) - as.integer(factor(id))) %in% c(0, 1)) %>%
    pull(value) %>%
    matrix(2) %>%
    t()

which gives
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    7
[2,]    2    8
[3,]    3    9
[4,]   10   16
[5,]   11   17
[6,]   18   24

